# Update multiple Firebase documents using an array of Document IDs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, foreach

I have an array of Strings which represent Firebase Document IDs like so:

```
var idArray = [“PuLDb90jgz3a5P8bLQoy”,  “PMKoZIp46umXQnUlA64a”,  “cVGbD3Wy4gWjZ9fZP7h1”]
```

This Array is dynamic and has been generated by a previous getDocuments call. It could have up to 15 ID strings in it, so it cannot be hard coded.

Within each Firebase Document I have an Int field called menuPosition set to a current value.

What I am trying to do is update each document which appears in the idArray and simply -1 from the menuPosition field value in one go.

What should be so straightforward is driving me crazy - does anyone know a simple way to do it? Obviously, if I put it in a for loop then the code will run too many times and my menuPosition value would be wrong. I just want each operation to perform once.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try using a transaction?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you have 15 document IDs, you'll need 15 calls to [update that document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data). What happens when you try that? Is there an error message?

Comment: The problem is that initially I make a call to Firebase to grab those ID's and setup the idArray then I need to update each document, I don't know how many IDs will be in that array until it's produced. If I run a for loop to update each document then it will -1 for however many times are in the array - which will make all of the values wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just run a loop over the document IDs and decrement the field in each iteration.

```
var idArray = ["J2LovReBF0v8F4e0RSBU", "UcW8tsgld2ZuUo92xfP8", "oHTJ4iO1NWCK7x1aryne"]

for docId in idArray {
    Firestore.firestore().document("someCollection/\(docId)").updateData([
        "menuPosition": FieldValue.increment(Int64(-1))
    ])
}
```

If you want this operation to be atomic then just wrap it in a batch write.

```
var idArray = ["J2LovReBF0v8F4e0RSBU", "UcW8tsgld2ZuUo92xfP8", "oHTJ4iO1NWCK7x1aryne"]
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let batch = db.batch()

for docId in idArray {
    batch.updateData([
        "menuPosition": FieldValue.increment(Int64(-1))
    ], forDocument: db.document("someCollection/\(docId)"))
}
batch.commit()
```